# Building error in Android Studio after including Google Cloud Client library

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

While trying to work with [Google Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries#gcloud-libraries), I added this dependency:
com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev17-1.19.0
However, I'm getting the following build error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class
```

Here's my list of dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev17-1.19.0'
}
```

What dependency exactly should be excluded for this javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an unnecessary JAR file (jsr305-1.3.9.jar) in libs directory, and I got this resolved simply by removing it.